# Floating image in an activity - android -

Tags: java, android, image, ontouch

I would like to create a picture/button that is displayed over the content of an activity and I can move it anywhere on the screen. Example of functionality: If I move it close to the left side of the screen I would like the image to move to the edge when the user drops the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a draggable view library like [DraggableView](https://github.com/elevenetc/DraggableView#draggableview) or you can implement your own `onTouch` handling to handle touch events for dragging image view. Here's an [article](http://www.singhajit.com/android-draggable-view/) for reference.